# Spreadsheet software analog whitch separates Data from Presentation

Tags: information-management, reporting, data, spreadsheet

Microsoft Excel mixes formating, presentation and data, that drives me crazy. I just can't use my poor data this way.

Is there a tool which works with data and tunes its reporting separately?

I can use Python with ML libraries or something, but prefer some user-friendly graphical application. Do you know one?

Comment: Why can't you enter your data on one worksheet and create your charts on another? You can reference cells and ranges on other worksheets (or even workbooks).

Comment: Because it is a hack.

Answer (score 1):

There is a python based spreadsheet [pyspread](https://manns.github.io/pyspread/) that is able to use python code directly in each cell, in fact each cell can contain a complete python program, that you might like to take a look at.

[image]

But I would also strongly suggest taking a look at [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) notebooks. They will let you obtain, store, manipulate, evaluate and present your data in a lot of ways. Take a look at some of the entries in ["A Gallery of interesting Jupyter Notebooks"](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/A-gallery-of-interesting-Jupyter-Notebooks) and give you a variety of methods to present your working and results.

[image]

All of the above software is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Widely Used